# Query custom post types by meta field in a term from custom taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I need to retrieve all custom posts that have terms from custom taxonomy assigned to them.

To be more precise:

There is `advertisers_cats` post type that has terms assigned from custom taxonomy `ss_category`. Some terms have a meta field callsed `ss_aff_category` set to `true`.

I have to retrieve all `advertisers_cats` posts that have `ss_category` terms with `ss_aff_category` set to `true`.

What direction should I takie to achieve this ?

So far I have come up with this arguments for my query:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => array('advertisers_cats'),
    'showposts' => 9,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ss_category',
            'terms' => array(100, 101),
            'field' => 'term_id',
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'rand');
```

This, however, does not allow me to select posts with `ss_category` terms that have `ss_aff_category` set to `true`.

Comment: Just so I understand your question, you're trying to get all posts in taxonomy `ss_category` that have the terms assigned to them `100` or `101` but you're not getting any results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the query works and you get all posts with `ss_category` terms (instead of those with `ss_aff_category = true` only), I think this should work:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => array('advertisers_cats'),
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ss_category',
            'terms' => array(100, 101),
            'field' => 'term_id',
        )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'ss_aff_category',
            'value' => true
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);
```

Note that I changed `showposts` to `posts_per_page`. You can also add `'post_status' => 'publish',` to exclude concepts and trash items.

Comment: You don't need to set post status, the default is `publish` for logged out users and `publish` and `private` for logged in users. You have to explicitely set `trash` and `draft` if you need posts from those statusses